# How to find shortest path in dynamic situation

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

Some days ago, Someone ask me, If we have some agents in our environment, and they want go from their sources to their destinations, how we can find the total shortest path for all of them such that they shouldn't have conflict during their walk.

The point of problem is all agents simultaneously walking in environment (which can be modeled by undirected weighted graph), and we shouldn't have any collision. I thought about this but I couldn't find optimum path for all of them. But sure there are too many heuristic ideas for this problem.

Assume input is graph G(V,E), m agents which are in: S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>,...,S<sub>m</sub> nodes of graph in startup and they should go to nodes D<sub>1</sub>,...D<sub>m</sub> at the end. Also may be there is conflict in nodes **S<sub>i</sub>** or **D<sub>i</sub>**,... but these conflicts are not important they shouldn't have conflict when they are in their internal nodes of their path.

If their path shouldn't have same internal node, It will be kind of [**`k-disjoint paths`**](http://www.shannarasite.org/kb/kbse48.html) problem which is NPC, but in this case paths can have same nodes, but agent shouldn't be in same node in same time. I don't know I can tell the exact problem statement or not. If is confusing tell me in comments to edit it.

Is there any optimal and fast algorithm (by optimal I mean sum of length of all paths be as smallest as possible, and by fast I mean good polynomial time algorithm).

Comment: Are the agents allowed to stay at a given node? Or do they have to walk in every iteration? (You could model a cost for staying by creating an edge going to the node itself)

Comment: @Zeta, In fact Yes, but I didn't say this because I thought it would be more complicated. But if you have solution for this it would be nice.

Comment: I don't have a solution (yet), sorry, but this will change the best possible solutions: [Example](http://i.imgur.com/I6vAP.png). If waiting is not allowed, then the min sum of all lengths is `100+100+2=202`. If waiting is allowed and costs less than 66 (say 40), then the min sum of all lengths is `40+1+1 + 40+40+1+1 + 2 = 42+82+2 = 126`.

Comment: @Zeta, good sample, but I think algorithm which is solves our current problem, can solve stay-in problem (as you said just adding loop to each node of graph).

Comment: I can almost guarantee you this is an NP-complete problem. I'd take a look at trying to prove it's NP complete.

Comment: How do you measure "shortest paths?" Do you mean that the total lengths of all the paths?  The length of just the longest path?  With multiple agents I could see either of these as reasonable options.

Comment: @ldog, wow, It's interesting, I'll be happy to see your proof.

Comment: @templatetypedef, yes both of them are reasonable, but I mean sum of weights of all paths.

Comment: I mention this because if you just want to minimize the sum of the path lengths, the original k-disjoint paths problem actually is solvable in polynomial time using a min-cost max-flow.

Comment: My mistake - I didn't realize that there were multiple start and end nodes.  When there is just one start/end node, then you can use the max-flow.  Sorry about that!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7904/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-templatetypedef)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Google search reveals two links that might be helpful:

- [Cooperative path planning for multi-robot systems in dynamic domains](http://www.intechopen.com/articles/show/title/cooperative-path-planning-for-multi-robot-systems-in-dynamic-domains)
- [Optimizing schedules for prioritized path planning of multi-robot systems](http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/Bennewitz01b.html)

**Edit:** From the book chapter (first link):

> There are various approaches to path planning in multi-robot system [sic], however, finding the
>   optimal solution is NP-hard. Hopcraft et al. (1984) simplify the planning problem to the
>   problem of moving rectangles in a rectangular container. They proved the NP-hardness of
>   finding a plan from a given configuration to a goal configuration with the least amount of
>   steps. Hence, all feasible approaches to path planning are a compromise between efficiency
>   and accuracy of the result.

I can't find the original paper by Hopcroft online, but given that quote, I suspect the problem they reduced the navigation task to is similar to [Rush Hour](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Rush_Hour_%28game%29), which is PSPACE-complete.

Comment: Your referenced papers talk about different heuristics, which is not hard (I mentioned that in my question), I'd asking about exact algorithm. May be for first OP (who asked me this question), heuristics are nice, but for me exact algorithm or NP-Completeness is interesting.

Comment: I updated the answer with a quote from the first link; the problem appears to be NP-hard.

Comment: Right, it'd be NP-hard, not NP-complete, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of getting from point a to point b for each robot, you could just use a search algorithm like **[A* (A Star)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)** or **[Best-First](http://Best-first%20search)**.

Give it a simple heuristic like the sum of distances from goal.

Comment: Simpler heuristic is finding shortest path for all of them, then run algorithm, if any robot has collision with others by some priority stop it, and run other robots, this algorithm is fast and terminates soon (is not hard to show this), I'm looking for exact algorithm.